# TextElement Enumerator Class Bug or (Tamil) Unicode Bug

Tags: c#, unicode, .net-2.0, tamil

why the TextElementEnumerator not properly parsing the Tamil Unicode character.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;

namespace Glyphtest
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            const string unicodetxt1 = "ஊரவர் கெளவை";
            List<string> output = Syllabify(unicodetxt1);
            Console.WriteLine(output.Count);
            const string unicodetxt2 = "கௌவை";
            output = Syllabify(unicodetxt2);
            Console.WriteLine(output.Count);
        }

        public static List<string> Syllabify(string unicodetext)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(unicodetext)) return null;
            TextElementEnumerator enumerator = StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator(unicodetext);
            var data = new List<string>();
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                data.Add(enumerator.Current.ToString());
            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

Following above code sample deals with Unicode character

'கௌ'->  0x0bc8 (க) +0xbcc(ௌ). (Correct Form)

'கௌ'->0x0bc8 (க) +0xbc6(ெ) + 0xbb3(ள) (In Correct Form)

Is it bug in [Text Element Enumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textelementenumerator.aspx) Class ,
why its not to Enumerate it properly from the string.

i.e 
கெளவை => 'கெள'+ 'வை'     has to enumerated in  Correct form

கெளவை => 'கெ'  +'ள'  +'வை' not to be enumerated in Incorrect form.

If so how to overcome this issue.

Comment: What's your question or problem?

Comment: Run the code and see the output string array content while on debug.see how the character has enumerated it in incorrect form.

Comment: First one does 8 where as second one does 2. What's your question in that? Which one is correct? first?

Comment: oh god 'கௌ' is a single character of visual glyph,it is not 'கெ' 'ள' two character visual glyph. please use charmap on windows, font latha and see difference.

Comment: Oh god am also tamil only man. But let me know what's the problem pls. I asked twice already. Atleast tell what is the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not been bug with Unicode character or [TextElementEnumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textelementenumerator.aspx) Class,
As specific to the lanaguage ([Tamil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamil_language))

letter made by any [Tamil consonants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamil_script) followed by visual glyph

for eg-
க  -\u0b95
ெ -\u0bc6 
ள -\u0bb3

form Tamil character 'கெள' while its seems similar to formation of visual glyph

க  -\u0b95
ௌ-\u0bcc

and its right form to solution.
hence before enumerating Tamil character we have replace irregular formation of character.

As with rule of Tamil Grammar ([ஔகாரக் குறுக்கம்](http://ta.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%AE%94%E0%AE%95%E0%AE%BE%E0%AE%B0%E0%AE%95%E0%AF%8D_%E0%AE%95%E0%AF%81%E0%AE%B1%E0%AF%81%E0%AE%95%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%95%E0%AE%AE%E0%AF%8D))
the visual glyph (ௌ) will come as starting letter of a word.

so that. the above code is to be should processed as

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        const string unicodetxt1 = "ஊரவர் கெளவை";
        List<string> output = Syllabify(unicodetxt1);
        Console.WriteLine(output.Count);
        const string unicodetxt2 = "கௌவை";
        output = Syllabify(unicodetxt2);
        Console.WriteLine(output.Count);
    }

    public static string CheckVisualGlyphPattern(string txt)
    {
        string[] data = txt.Split(new[] { ' ', '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        string list = string.Empty;
        var rx = new Regex("^(.*?){1}(\u0bc6){1}(\u0bb3){1}");
        foreach (string s in data)
        {
            var matches = new List<Match>();
            string outputs = rx.Replace(s, match =>
            {
                matches.Add(match);
                return string.Format("{0}\u0bcc", match.Groups[1].Value);
            });
            list += string.Format("{0} ", outputs);
        }
        return list.Trim();
    }

    public static List<string> Syllabify(string unicodetext)
    {
        var processdata = CheckVisualGlyphPattern(unicodetext);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(processdata)) return null;
        TextElementEnumerator enumerator = StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator(processdata);
        var data = new List<string>();
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            data.Add(enumerator.Current.ToString());
        return data;
    }
}
```

It produce the appropriate visual glyph while enumerating.

Answer (score 0):

U+0BB3 ᴛᴀᴍɪʟ ʟᴇᴛᴛᴇʀ ʟʟᴀ has Grapheme_Cluster_Break=XX (Other). This makes the grapheme clusters <U+0BC8 U+0BC6><U+0BB3> the correct ones since there is always a grapheme cluster break before characters with Grapheme_Cluster_Break equal to Other.

<U+0BC8 U+0BCC> has no internal grapheme cluster breaks because U+0BCC has Grapheme_Cluster_Break=SpacingMark and there are usually no breaks before such characters (exceptions are at the start of text or when preceded by a control character).

Well, at least this is what the Unicode standard has to say (http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Grapheme_Cluster_Boundaries).

Now, I have no idea of how Tamil works, so take what follows with a pinch of salt.

U+0BCC decomposes into <U+0BC6 U+0BD7>, meaning the two sequences (<U+0BC8 U+0BC6 U+0BB3> and <U+0BC8 U+0BCC>) not canonically equivalent, so there is no requirement for grapheme cluster segmentation to yield the same results.

When I look at it with my Tamil-ignorant eyes, it seems U+0BCC ᴛᴀᴍɪʟ ᴀᴜ ʟᴇɴɢᴛʜ ᴍᴀʀᴋ and U+0BB3 ᴛᴀᴍɪʟ ʟᴇᴛᴛᴇʀ ʟʟᴀ look exactly the same. However, U+0BCC is a spacing mark, but U+0BB3 isn't. If you use U+0BCC in the input instead of U+0BB3, the result is what you expected.

Going on a limb, I will say that you are using the wrong character but, again, I don't know Tamil at all so I can't be sure.